# Mutability issue with self and collections in Rust

Tags: rust, mutability

I am writing a [simple library](https://github.com/locka99/deckofcards-rs/blob/master/src/deck.rs) in Rust that manages a deck of cards. It has functions to shuffle, deal cards etc.

The shuffle() function takes a mutable reference to self that allows the existing deck to be reshuffled. It should be pretty straightforward:

1. Create a temporary collection from the deck containing a tuple with a card and a random number.
2. Sort the collection by the random number.
3. Rebuild the existing deck using the order of the temporary collection.

The code for this would be as follows.

```
pub struct Deck {
    // A deck contains zero or more cards
    cards: Vec<Card>
}

impl Deck {

// shuffle
pub fn shuffle(&mut self) {
    if self.cards.is_empty() {
        return;
    }

    let mut shuffler : Vec<(&Card, u32)> = Vec::with_capacity(self.cards.len());

    for card in self.cards.iter() {
        // make a tuple consisting of each card in the input and a random number
        let card_pos = (card, rand::thread_rng().gen::<u32>());
        shuffler.push(card_pos);
    }

    // Sort the vector
    shuffler.sort_by_key(|k| k.1);

    // Clear the cards
    self.cards.clear();

    // Put the cards into the new randomized order
    for card_pos in shuffler {
        let (card, _) = card_pos;
        self.cards.push(*card)
    }
}

}
```

The issue I have is this won't compile because I get errors.

```
src\deck.rs:85:9: 85:19 error: cannot borrow `self.cards` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable [E0502]                                                                                           
src\deck.rs:85         self.cards.clear();                                                              
                       ^~~~~~~~~~                                                                       
src\deck.rs:75:15: 75:25 note: previous borrow of `self.cards` occurs here; the immutable borrow prevents subsequent moves or mutable borrows of `self.cards` until the borrow ends                             
src\deck.rs:75          for card in self.cards.iter() {                                                 
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~                                                          
src\deck.rs:92:6: 92:6 note: previous borrow ends here                                                  
src\deck.rs:68     pub fn shuffle(&mut self) {                                                          
...                                                                                                     
src\deck.rs:92     }                                                                                    
                   ^                                                                                    
src\deck.rs:90:13: 90:23 error: cannot borrow `self.cards` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable [E0502]                                                                                          
src\deck.rs:90             self.cards.push(*card)                                                       
                           ^~~~~~~~~~                                                                   
src\deck.rs:75:15: 75:25 note: previous borrow of `self.cards` occurs here; the immutable borrow prevent
s subsequent moves or mutable borrows of `self.cards` until the borrow ends                             
src\deck.rs:75          for card in self.cards.iter() {                                                 
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~                                                          
src\deck.rs:92:6: 92:6 note: previous borrow ends here                                                  
src\deck.rs:68     pub fn shuffle(&mut self) {                                                          
...                                                                                                     
src\deck.rs:92     }
```

The errors complain of mutability which I assume to mean that it doesn't like that I've more than one mutable reference in scope or something but I don't know how to fix it. I've tried using brace delimiters to make blocks for each action but to no avail. I could probably break this up into more than one function but I'd rather it was a single function. How do I make this work with the least amount of effort?

NB I haven't tested the sort functionality yet so I hope sort_by_key does what I think but that's only going to matter after I resolve this first issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shuffler` is of type `Vec<(&Card, u32)>`, i.e. the `card` is a *reference*. That is, it's a pointer at the `Card` object stored in the buffer underlying the `self.cards` vector. So `self.cards.clear()` would delete the memory under `shuffler`'s feet!

Luckily there is an easy fix: Don't take references and clear the vector, *move the cards out of* `self.cards` with `drain`:

```
let mut shuffler: Vec<(Card, u32)> = Vec::with_capacity(self.cards.len());
for card in self.cards.drain(..) {
    let card_pos = (card, rand::thread_rng().gen::<u32>());
    shuffler.push(card_pos);
}
shuffler.sort_by_key(|k| k.1);
for card_pos in shuffler {
    let (card, _) = card_pos;
    self.cards.push(card);
}
```

Aside: There is an in-place shuffling algorithm that is also more efficient than sorting—linear time instead of O(n log n), and better constant factors—the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I had tried previously without using refs and I was getting other errors but of a similar kind. I'll keep the shuffle algorithm in mind since I may as well make it as efficient as possible.